# How to choose namespace and page names in dokuwiki, so that indexmenu and pagenav play nicely with useheading?

Tags: namespaces, dokuwiki

am about to move a user manual that previously lived in a pdf to dokuwiki. Before I start moving all the content, I want to make sure I can get the following components to interact nicely:

indexmenu, useheading, pagenav, bookcreator.

In my small scale testing, I so far couldn't achieve what I wanted.

**Goal:** I want side bar navigation and next and forward buttons on each page that navigate like you'd expect in a book.

I have two main sections that each contain a number of namesspaces (am thinking of them as sections that contain subsections) and pages (which don't have subsections now, but may have some in the future).

In the long run, I'd like to use bookcreator to use the order in the sidebar.

I drew you a picture, but am not allowed to post it, so here is a link:

http://images.labtutor.com/images/pagenav.png

**Steps taken:** I've turned on useheadings (it made 'You are here' navigation pretty), played with indexmenu and pagenav, and started all pages and namespaces with prefixes of 010, 020, 030 etc.

In my example, 010 and 020 are just pages, 030 is a namespace with two pages in that namespace.

**What I got (but don't want):** indexmenu builds the sidebar with 030 namespaces first, then pages. The pages are sorted alphabetically, not by prefix. The sort options make little sense to me and I've played with this for a while without success.

http://images.labtutor.com/images/pagenavbad.png

pagenav doesn't dip into namespaces when I'd expect it to go into a subsection (page in a namespace). That means if I get this:

Introduction page (click next ->) How to get going (click next ->) Some details (click next ->) Troubleshooting.

I suspect I have either a fundamental misunderstanding about how to use pages and namespaces, or ... well, else.

Thanks for your help!